Trying to read a .wav file but was able to convert only 20s conversation
I am trying to read a .wav file but was able to convert only 20s conversation into text.
   # code to read .wav file 
   import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    audio = r"D:\Fraud_Call_Detection\audio1.wav"
    with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        print ('Done!')

    try:
        
        text = (r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-HK"))
        print (text)

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

Output:

